# What is a monotonic increasing function $[0,1] \to [0,1]$?

Tags: functions

I am looking for a monotonic increasing function in $[0,1]$ , with the following specification:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(1) = 1$
- should contain one parameter
- for a given choice of this parameter should give the identity function $f(x) = x$
- for other values of the parameter the shape shall be skewed, like $f(0.25) = 0.5$ , $f(0.75) = 0.9$ or something.
- should be continuous
- should be strong monotonic increasing, i.e. $f(a)>f(b)$ if $a>b$.
- should be in closed form.

I am not sure how to describe it better, so please ask if something is unclear.

Comment: The obvious choice is $f(x) = 0$ on $[0, a]$, and $f(x) = 1$ on $(a, 1]$. If you want a continuous function, you could instead linearly interpolate between points $(a, 0)$ and $(1,1)$. If you want a differentiable one, you could do the usual smoothing-out trick at point $(a, 0)$ using a multiple of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. Function should be continuous...

Comment: There are many choices, for example $x^\alpha$ for suitable $\alpha$,  which could be constant but need not be.

Comment: Linearly interpolate between the points $(0,0), (a, 1-a), (1,1)$.

Comment: Of course the power function, thats what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot André, that is the function I was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome.  For your example, $\alpha=1/2$ will give a sort of OK fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As André Nicolas wrote in the comments:

> There are many choices, for example $x^\alpha$ for suitable $\alpha$, which could be constant but need not be. For your example, $\alpha=1/2$ will give a sort of OK fit.